# Is it possible to show an specific product attribute in Elementor product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, elementor

I'm trying to add a specific product attribute ( in this case, the "warranty" ) to the elementor custom product page.
I have tried using "PHP Code Snippets" plugin and adding:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_after_price', 15 );
function product_attribute_after_price () {
    global $product;

    // HERE add your product attribute SLUG or taxonomy
    $attribute_slug = 'guarantee';

    $taxonomy = strpos($url, 'blog') !== false ? $attribute_slug : 'pa_' . $attribute_slug;
    $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy ); // The value

    if( empty($term_name) ) return; // Exit if empty value

    // If not empty we display it
    $output  = '<div class="product-attribute '.$taxonomy.'"><p>';
    $output .= '<strong> '.$attribute_name.'</strong>: ';
    $output .= '<span> '.$term_name.'</span>';
    echo $output . '</p></div>';
}
```

but that shows nothing.

what should i do?

Comment: Hi Aliz, in youe case i think custom field is a better solution!